# Cannot boot from USB to install 12.10

Tags: boot, live-usb, 12.10, bios

i am a long time user of Ubuntu and this is the first time a such thing happens to me.
I usually upgrade from a version to an other, but this time i wish to do a clean install.
I want to totally remove my 12.04 and do a clean install of 12.10, i created a live USB then i restarted my computer to boot from USB, i got the following error:

**Product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
US5,434,872, US5,732,894, (*and many more*)**

Under that i see:

**PCIe GBE Family Controller Series v2.38**

**Media test failiure**

**Exiting PXE ROM**

And then it reboots

I've searched a lot for an answer, i guess the problem is with something in my bios, but i didn't find a fix.

I would really appreciate a fix for my problem.
My laptop is a Toshiba p775 dual boot ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of the new UEFI thing that they've introduced in this version.
Open the BIOS and try to find and see if you have UEFI option in there. If you have it, make sure it is disabled. If it is disabled, try to enable it :)

Comment: hello i looked everywhere in the bios and didn't find a UEFI option :S